# if HTTP is stateless how can PHP know when a window is closed (for session termination)

Tags: php, http

I'm having trouble understanding a concept. If HTTP is stateless and sessions depend on the session cookie, how can PHP terminate a session on window close since another http request is never made?

Comment: The session will be terminated if the session lifetime has been exceeded. With every request from the same client, the session lifetime will be renewed. So the session dies after the client doesn't send a new request in the configured timespan.

Comment: ^ in short: PHP **doesn't** know that the window has been closed.

Comment: If you mean that you are logged out after closing your browser: That's because the cookie that holds the session token is usually a [Session cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Session_cookies). Meaning it expires as soon as the browser closes. The session on the server side still exists (until it timed out), it's just that the browser doesn't know the token it was using previously.

Comment: @Ivar so if you set the session.cookie_lifetime to 0 and you don't make another http request to the server to refresh the cookie (close the browser/visit another site) the cookie expires and thus the session (for all intensive purposes for the user) has expired. The only thing here is that visiting another site is not closing the browser.

Comment: Visiting another site does not expire the session cookie indeed (Unless it's for a longer period then the session's lifespan). What makes you think that a session is expired when you visit another website?

Comment: @Ivar because there would be noting to extend the life of the session cookie (another http request to the server that assigned the session cookie)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP app terminates the session by deleting the cookie on the server side, so when the browser tries to access a resource and passes in the old cookie, the server doesn't recognize the value as being valid and refuses access to the service. It can also delete the cookie value on the server side after a time period has expired.

The browsers are supposed to delete the session cookies when the browser is closed or the cookie expires, but there's actually no guarantee that this will happen. Deleting them on the server ensures that they are no longer valid.